# What is exactly meant by waves travelling along same direction?

Tags: waves, wavefunction

I read that Beats are heard when sound waves with same amplitude and a small difference in frequency are travelling along the same direction are superimposed, but in problems related to frequency, the sources of the two sound waves that are superimposed are not the same,hence, when they superimpose at a point, and we are asked to find the beats produced by the resultant, how is it possible that both the waves are travelling along the same direction?

Comment: is it possible to revise the syntax so there is more than a single long sentence full of commas?

Answer (score 1):

I think the "travelling along the same direction" part is irrelevant - in many circumstances sound waves will spread out in all directions, rather than being channelled in a single direction.

The only criterion for hearing beats is that the superimposed sound waves have frequencies that are close but not the same. It does not matter if they have different sources or are travelling in different directions. You can even hear beats with stereo headphones if two different frequencies are panned to the right and left respectively.

Comment: ,so beats are produced when any two waves with same Amplitude and small difference in frequency are superimposed?

Comment: But then why do most textbooks say that the waves should travel along the same direction?

Comment: @AdityaMukherjee Well, any textbook that says that the waves must travel in the same direction to cause beats is clearly wrong. The waves do not even have to be the same amplitude - although they should have similar amplitudes, otherwise the louder sound will dominate the quieter one. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_(acoustics) for more information.